# Greatest and smallest number not print

Tags: c++

it works for greatest num but not work for smallest num plz check what is prblm in this code.when i run this program it show the greatest num but not show the smallest num.i dnt knw what is metter in this situation suggest me some ur important opnion.
 suppose that i have to enter data
10
55
2
44
it shhow the output greatest no is 55
but should to show the result 
greatest no is 55 
and smallest no is 2

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int a,b,c,d,max,min;
cout<<"enter 1st number:";
cin>>a;
cout<<"enter 2nd number:";
cin>>b;
cout<<"enter 3rd number:";
cin>>c;
cout<<"enter 4th number:";
cin>>d;
if(a>b)
{
if(a>c)
{
if(a>d)
{
cout<<a<<" is greatest";
}
}
}
else if(b>c)
{

if(b>d)
{
cout<<b<<" is greatest";
}
}
else if(c>d)
{

cout<<c<<" is greatest";
}
else
{

cout<<d<<" is greatest";
}
if(a<b)
{

if(a<c)
{

if(a<d)
{

cout<<a<<" is smallest";
}
}
}
else if(b<c)
{

if(b<d)
{

cout<<b <<" is smallest";
}
}

else if(c<d)
{

cout<<c<<" is smallest";
}
else
{

cout<<d<<" is smallest"; 
}
return (0);
}
```

Comment: That is a really terrible way to go about it. Have you looked into using loops? Think about if you had 10 numbers, or 100, or 1000. Do you want to sit there and write that many `if` statements?

Comment: i want use the different technique so i chose this technique for learning

Comment: can u tell me where is the problem in my code

Comment: why dont show the smallest no

Comment: You should do a few things to your question. __1.__ Indent your code. (Which might even help you discover the bug). __2.__ Give example input data. __3.__ Given that input data, what do you currently see as the output. __4.__ Why is that output wrong, and what should it actually be. __5.__ plz is not a word.

Comment: suppose i have to enter the data
10
44
2
55
it show the result 
the greatest no is 55
actualy should to display the 
greatest no is 55 
and smallest no is 5

Answer (score 0):

Suppose a>b, a>c and a

Your first if bloc fails:

```
if (a>b)  // yes
{
    if (a>c)  // yes 
    {
        if (a>d) // <=== false but no else clause for this one !!
        {
            cout << a << " is greatest";
        }
    }
}
```

Your code will then skip all related else clauses, and go on with remaining if:

```
if (a<b)  // fails 
{
    if (a<c)
    {
        if (a<d)
        {
            cout << a << " is smallest";
        }
```

It will then skip the else clauses, and oops !  you're at the end of the code and didn't print anything !

Comment: When @Cyber told you that you've chosen a terrible way to solve this problem, you said that it was your choice for learning.  If I now would correct your code, you would no longer have opportunity to learn...

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, I would use something more extensible. Put all your numbers in a `std::vector<int>` then use `std::max_element` and `std::min_element` to find the max and min values respectively.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    int a,b,c,d;
    std::cout<<"enter 1st number:";
    std::cin>>a;
    std::cout<<"enter 2nd number:";
    std::cin>>b;
    std::cout<<"enter 3rd number:";
    std::cin>>c;
    std::cout<<"enter 4th number:";
    std::cin>>d;

    std::vector<int> numbers = {a,b,c,d};

    auto largest = std::max_element(begin(numbers), end(numbers));
    std::cout << "max element is: " << *largest << '\n';

    auto smallest = std::min_element(begin(numbers), end(numbers));
    std::cout << "min element is: " << *smallest << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

[Working example](http://ideone.com/ezJDf9)